# 700x25c tubes inside 700x23c tyre

Tags: road-bike, innertube

I'm riding on 700x23c tyres with 700x23c tubes, road bike. I've obtained a box of 700x25c tubes. While I'm taking the approach that it's always best to fit the correct size, I'd like to either use, sell or give away these 700x25c tubes.

If I use them:

- Will I encounter problems?
- How soon will these issues occur?
- What sort of problems may occur?

There is a similar question, although it deals with borderline issues, not explicitly with incorrect sizes.

[What inner tube size to get for my road bike?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/32325/41088)

Comment: Usually tubes in that size range come with a *range* of suitable sizes listed, like 18-25. I'd think the difference in size between a 23 and a 25 definitely falls in the "borderline" area.  If it's a "big" 25 tube and you have a "small" 23 tire, you might have some problems.  Otherwise, I'd say it's likely you can use those tubes in your 23 tires with no issues.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'm thinking that one problem I may encounter with a larger tube is when I inflate close to the tyres rated 120psi. I usually like to ride on 80-90 psi, so I won't be at the extreme. Would you or anyone else think that the tyre walls may have issues holding back an oversized tube?

Comment: What happens to a 23 tube if you inflate it to 120 psi outside of a tire?  What happens to a 25 tube if you do the same?  Neither tube is going to significantly reduce the force of the air against the tire.  All bicycle tubes do is hold air in - they don't support themselves at all.  The only thing holding bicycle tubes together when pumped up are the rims and the tires.

Comment: There's more room to expand in a 25 tube, so, I guess the pressure on the 23 tyre wall would be greater.

Comment: 90 psi is 90 psi.  Again - as long as the tube isn't so stretched that it's prone to failure, or doesn't have enough room to expand smoothly and creates kinks/folds, the tube doesn't matter.  The tube doesn't stop the air from expanding - the tire and the rim do that.  The tube **only** stops the air from leaking through.  The tube is nothing more than a balloon thick enough to withstand *some* rough treatment.

Comment: Having a slightly over-sized tube will not cause problems with high inflation pressures -- so long as  the tube is not so large as to fold up on itself inside the tire there will be no problem

Comment: Ok. So I guess it's safe to assume that as long as the tube is placed neatly inside the tyre, so as to avoid folds, twists and kinks, there shouldnt be any major problems. The problems then could be that it's more difficult to ensure a clean smooth install because the tube itself is slightly larger than the tyre and there may be some excess rubber somewhere.

Comment: (Understand that the pressure "held" by a standard tube is miniscule -- five pounds at most.  The tube has virtually no effect on the max pressure capacity of the tire.)

Comment: The "ideal" size for a tube is to be slightly smaller than the tire, to minimize difficulties with mounting.  Your x25 tubes are only very slightly larger than the x23 ones and very likely will still be very slightly "undersized".  Again, check the box and the side of the tube -- there will a range of sizes listed, and you may find you've been worrying for nothing.

Comment: A naked tube will split somewhere between 15 and ~40 PSI.  Talk of inflating one to 120 PSI is not real-world.   Don't believe me?  Give it a try (with earmuffs)

Comment: @Criggie I meant 120psi while in the tyre.

Comment: I just realized that i ride my 23mm trainer tire since the beginning of this winter with the same tube i use for the 28mm tires i ride normally. So far i had no problems on the trainer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They'll be fine - I'd certainly use them without question in a 23mm tyre.

Most tubes cover a range like 18-25 and 25-38.  Given 23 and 25 are in the same range I'd expect it to work correctly.

If you have access to a spare 23 and these 25mm tubes, compare them.  I bet they're identical in size, or so close to it that the difference is immaterial.

Tubes are consumables, you'll use them up eventually.

Other options:

- Stick one in your saddle bag as the last resort second spare.
- Give them away.
- Buy a 25mm tyre and try it out (if your bike frame can fit one)

Comment: @normon feel free to add your own answer - This answer is that they're essentially the same size, and there's no increase risk of folding.  Its not like you're shoving a 40mm tube in a 25mm tyre.